# Should we split up the midrash tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

When I asked a [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41240/5323) recently about a drasha for a specific din, I had some trouble choosing the tag for "drasha." In the end, I chose [exegesis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exegesis), but then realized that the only other question with that tag was Baby Seal's [Pardes question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35859/5323), which is more of a question about "drasha theory" then about specific drashos. A [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16510241#16510241) with DoubleAA led me to use the [midrash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midrash) tag.

But....I still don't think that this is the right tag, because a cursory look at the question that fall under that tag reveals that some are questions about specific drashos [system of exegesis] ([1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41240/5323), [2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29302/5323), [3](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27717/5323)), while others are questions about the Midrash [books that explain Torah, such as Midrash Tanchuma, Toras Kohanim et al]  ([1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40148/5323), [2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40327/5323), [3](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/39099/5323)).

Therefore, I think that the [midrash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midrash) tag should be split in two: with questions about aggadta and the books Midrash staying with [midrash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midrash), and a new tag ("drashos"? "drashos-exegesis"?) for questions about specific, halachic, drashos.

---

The current tag description for the [midrash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midrash) tag is "Exegetical interpretation, often of verses in Tanach. The term also refers to books based on these interpretations, e.g., Midrash Rabba, Midrash Tanchuma, et al." .....I think that we should leave the second half of the description ("*books based on these interpretations, e.g., Midrash Rabba, Midrash Tanchuma, et al.*") with the the [midrash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midrash) tag, and the first half ("*Exegetical interpretation, often of verses in Tanach.*") with the new tag.

Comment: There is also [tag:agada-stories-legends]

Comment: But that's more for stories, no? ....and a lot of them about recent stories too

Comment: Note that _d'rashos_ that affect _halacha_ are instancs of what's called _midrash halacha_.

Comment: I don't think we should split it, as proposed here, into two tags, one for aggadic _d'rashos_ and the _midrash_ books and the other for halachic _d'rashos_. After all, why lump questions about the books (e.g. _Toras Kohanim_) in with questions about aggadic _midrashim_?

Comment: @msh210 About your first comment -- maybe "midrash" and "midrash-halacha"?

Comment: @Shokhet In that case, maybe 'midrash-aggada' and 'midrash-halacha'?

Comment: @msh210 Maybe...but then where would questions about the books themselves go? ....didn't look, but questions about who wrote them and when etc are possible

Comment: @Shokhet, why not 'midrash-aggada' or 'midrash-halacha', depending as which is being asked about?

Comment: @msh210 That makes sense....idk how Meta works; should I edit my question to reflect my change of mind?

Comment: @Shokhet, [the current votes on it reflect (well, the current vote on it reflects) how people agree or disagree with it](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). How about posting an answer with this new idea, and people can vote on that, too.

Comment: @msh210 Alrighty then.

Answer (score 2):

msh210 [came up with](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/should-we-split-up-the-midrash-tag?noredirect=1#comment8070_2096) a better idea -- instead of leaving the [midrash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midrash) tag as it is, and creating a new tag for midrashei halacha, *two* new tags should be created, deleting the [midrash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midrash) tag:

1. "Midrash-aggada," to deal with questions about the stories and the books containing the stories.
2. "Midrash-halacha," to deal with questions about halachically significant derashos, and the books where they may be found.

Thoughts?